# Non-Blocking Thrift Server in C++ and Thrift Client in Python

Tags: c++, python, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a non-blocking multi-threaded thrift server written in C++ and a thrift client written in python. Below code snippets briefly shows how the thrift protocol and binding configurations are done in both C++ server and python client.

My problem is that when the python client makes a call to the C++ server via thrift I get an error saying "**thrift non-blocking server overload condition**" in the C++ server output (i.e. terminal), which have been indicated in the 3rd and 4th snippets below. I am enclosing the stack that is retrieved via GDB backtrace command as well for your information. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? What do you think could be the possible cause of this error. Is there st wrong in the thrift configuration in python side or C++ side. Please refer to the below snippets. I made a lot of googling but could not find a clue so far. Thanks.

**1) Python Client - Thrift Configuration**

```
     try:
        self.transport = TSocket.TSocket( host , port)
        <----- NONBLOCKING --------->
        self.transport = TTransport.TFramedTransport(self.transport)    
        <----- NONBLOCKING --------->
        protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(self.transport)


        # Instantiate the thrift client
        self.client = MyService.Client(protocol)
        # Connect to the thrift server
        self.transport.open()
        print 'Connection established via thrift...\n'
```

**2) C++ server - Thrift configuration**

```
    using boost::shared_ptr;
    printf("          *** Starting non-block THRIFT! ***\n");
    shared_ptr<MyServiceHandler> handler(new MyServiceHandler(this));
    shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new MyServiceProcessor(handler));
    shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    shared_ptr<ThreadManager>  threadManager=ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(15);
    shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory> threadFactory =
    shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory>(new PosixThreadFactory());
    threadManager->threadFactory(threadFactory);
    threadManager->start();
    ats::TNonblockingServer server(processor,protocolFactory, port, threadManager);
    server.serve();
```

**3) Error Output in C++ server**

```
   !!!! ERROR BEGIN !!!! 
   Thrift: Tue Nov 15 17:59:49 2011 **thrift non-blocking server overload condition**
   !!!! ERROR IS END !!!!
```

**4) GDB Backtrace Stack**

```
   thrift non-blocking server overload condition

   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   [Switching to Thread 0xb7ad7b70 (LWP 17961)]
   0x080bb3a8 in vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info ()
  (gdb) bt
  #0 0x080bb3a8 in vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info ()
  #1 0xb7ec8195 in apache::thrift::server::TConnection::workSocket (this=0x80be4f0)
  at src/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp:168
  #2 0xb7ecc88d in apache::thrift::server::TConnection::eventHandler (fd=13, v=0x80be4f0)
  at src/server/TNonblockingServer.h:915
  #3 0xb7ea8e90 in event_base_loop () from /usr/lib/libevent-1.4.so.2
  #4 0xb7ec782f in apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::serve (this=0xb7ad7194)
  at src/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp:923
  #5 0x0807bef5 in MyConfiguration::runNonBlockingServer (this=0xbffff2ec, port=9090)
  at /home/configuration/my_configuration.cpp:485
  #6 0x0807de19 in MyConfiguration::run (this=0xbffff2ec)
  at /home/configuration/my_configuration.cpp:54
  #7 0x08078a2a in redirectPthreadRun (m=0xbffff2ec)
  at /home/src/common/p_thread_run.cpp:107
  #8 0xb7fa0725 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  #9 0xb7ceb1ce in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Don't think this will address your problem, but a minor note - I am not sure of your calling context, but something like this: `shared_ptr<MyServiceHandler> handler(new MyServiceHandler(this));` had introduced a subtle double-free error for me. I would recommend having a separate `handler` class, an object of which is then instantiated within the 'server start' context.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution finally to this pb ? I've a close issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586340/tnonblockingserver-in-thrift-crashes-when-tframedtransport-opens