# TNonblockingServer in thrift crashes when TFramedTransport opens

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, thrift

I've been trying to implement a thrift server in C++ to communicate with a Python client.

here is my code:

C++ server:

```
shared_ptr<ThriftHandler> _handler (new myHandler());
shared_ptr<TProcessor> _processor (new myService(_handler));
shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> _protocolFactory (new TBinaryProtocolFactory());
shared_ptr<ThreadManager> _threadManager = ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(15);
shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory> _threadFactory(new PosixThreadFactory());
_threadManager->threadFactory(_threadFactory);
_threadManager->start();

shared_ptr<TNonblockingServer> _server(new TNonblockingServer(_processor, _protocolFactory, 9090 ,_threadManager));;
_server->serve();
```

Python Client code:

```
transport = TSocket.TSocket(host, port)
transport = TTransport.TFramedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
client = MyService.Client(protocol)
transport.open()
log.info("connection success!")
```

When I start the server and then the client, I get the following:

On the client side (Python):

```
./myPythonExec.py
connection success!
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

On the server side (c++):

```
assertion " 0 " failed
0  0x00007ffff0942425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
1  0x00007ffff0945b8b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
2  0x00007ffff093b0ee in __assert_fail_base (fmt=<optimized out>, assertion=0x7ffff1438f1a "0", 
file=0x7ffff1439298 "src/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp", line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>) at assert.c:94
3  0x00007ffff093b192 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7ffff1438f1a "0", file=0x7ffff1439298 "src/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp", 
line=558, function=0x7ffff1439c60 "void apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::TConnection::workSocket()") at assert.c:103
4  0x00007ffff14336e4 in apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::TConnection::workSocket (this=0x7fffc0004ac0)
at src/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp:558
5  0x00007ffff11ed94c in event_base_loop () from /usr/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5
```

I'm using libthrift 0.8.0 and have the same pb with libthrift 0.9.1

It works perfectly when using a TSimpleServer on C++ and a TBufferedTransport on the client side

Comment: Can you reproduce this with current trunk? If yes, please file a JIRA ticket.

Comment: thx for the answer. I just tested it with libthrift 0.9.1 and I have the same problem. I created an issue on JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2243

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, have not seen earlier, but looks like the same issue:
[Service Multiplexing using Apache Thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614648/service-multiplexing-using-apache-thrift/19647247#19647247)

In short, you have to use either framed on both sides, or none.

```
shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> _transportFactory(new TFramedTransportFactory());
shared_ptr<TNonblockingServer> _server(
   new TNonblockingServer(
     _processor, 
     _transportFactory,
     _transportFactory,
     _protocolFactory, 
     _protocolFactory, 
     9090,
     _threadManager));
_server->serve();
```

Comment: After looking again at it, I think you are right and it is indeed a bug with TNonblockingServer. Thanks for your patience ;-)

Comment: no pb :) don't hesitate to ask me if you have troubles reproducting it