# Service Multiplexing using Apache Thrift

Tags: java, service, thrift, multiplexing

Server code:

```
            TMultiplexedProcessor processor = new TMultiplexedProcessor();

            processor.registerProcessor(
                "AddService",
                new AddService.Processor(new AddHandler()));

            processor.registerProcessor(
                "MultiplyService",
                new MultiplyService.Processor(new MultiplyHandler()));

            TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(7911);



            TSimpleServer server = new TSimpleServer(new TSimpleServer.Args(serverTransport).
                   processor(processor));

            System.out.println("Starting server on port 7911 ...");
            server.serve();
```

Client Code:

```
    TFramedTransport transport;

   transport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("localhost", 7911));  
   transport.open();  


   TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

   System.out.println("1");
   TMultiplexedProtocol mp = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, "AddService");
   AddService.Client service = new AddService.Client(mp);

   System.out.println("2");
   TMultiplexedProtocol mp2 = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, "MultiplyService");
   MultiplyService.Client service2 = new MultiplyService.Client(mp2);

   System.out.println("3");

   System.out.println(service.add(2,2));
   System.out.println(service2.multiply(2000,200));
```

But when I am running the server(listening on port 7911) and the client, the client doesnt process the last two calls to the add/multiply functions.

I could debug that the arguments have been sent to the server, but the server is not able to process them.

Any pointers as to what i am missing?

Comment: Could be helpful to know the language, especially with Thrift as a multi-language RPC framework. C#? C++? Java? System.out.println() looks like the latter ...

Comment: This is in java only.. Both the client and the server

Comment: Ok, what means "the server is not able to process them" exactly? Do you get an error message, or what else?

Comment: The server runs, but doesnt produce results. I have put debug statements as you can see...So the debug output is :                  1                                                                   2                                                                   3                                                                     but doesnt print anything else...i have debug statements in the handler code as well but they dont appear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested, but it looks very much like as if you run two different protocol stacks on server and client. Try this:

```
TMultiplexedProcessor processor = new TMultiplexedProcessor();

processor.registerProcessor(
    "AddService",
    new AddService.Processor(new AddHandler()));

processor.registerProcessor(
    "MultiplyService",
    new MultiplyService.Processor(new MultiplyHandler()));

TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(7911);

TTransportFactory factory = new TFramedTransport.Factory();

TServer.Args args = new TServer.Args(serverTransport);
args.processor(processor);
args.transportFactory(factory);
TSimpleServer server = new TSimpleServer(args);

System.out.println("Starting server on port 7911 ...");
server.serve();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it works, but could you  please point me to a link that discusses the compatiable protocaol stacks

Comment: That's not really complicated. The entire stack consists of (1) a protocol (2) an endpoint transport and (3) optionally additional layered transport(s). In your sample this is (1) binary protocol (2) socket transport, (3) multiplexed + framed fransports. You simply have to ensure that both sides are using the exact same mix of these ingredients. That's all. A good in-depth explanation for beginners is Randy Abernethy's forthcoming book, already partially available via MEAP: http://www.manning.com/abernethy/